# Reverse the order of inline blocks?

Tags: html, css

As of current this set up aligns 2 boxes side by side but then when the container get's to small then the boxes stack up on each other as seen by this jsfiddle created by someone who helped me out last time: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gW8r2/1/

My Question is if it's possible to reverse the order it stacks so the box on the right (blue) stacks on top of left box when the container becomes too small?

Code shown on JSFiddle

CSS:

```
.parent {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid green;
text-align: center;
}

.parent > div {
display: inline-block;
}

.a {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
}

.b {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to go with `@media` queries in order to apply [`rotate()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#funcdef-rotate) [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) function to the `.parent` and its children:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .parent {
        -webkit-transform:  rotate(180deg);
        transform:  rotate(180deg);
    }

    .parent > div {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 5px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
}
```

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/gW8r2/9/)**.

It's worth noting that `@media` queries and CSS transforms are supported in **IE9+**.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment! Sadly when trying to implement this to my code it doesn't seem to do the effect your code successfully done. Here is my Jsfiddle as you can see same code as yours but I may have slightly broken something which breaks the effect! [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gW8r2/11/)

Comment: @LukeScotney93 You should choose a proper break point for the media query rule, something like: `max-width: 686px` where `686px` comes from `480px` red + `200px` blue + `5px` blue margin + `1px` for assurance = `686px`. **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/gW8r2/13/).**

Comment: Perfect! I was having trouble but then realised it was asking for media screen max-width and not it's container so had to calculate all the elements which make up the entire page to create the break point which was around 1270 in the end! Either way thank you very much for your patience and helping me with this!

Comment: @LukeScotney93 Don't mention it. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: So clever! I'm going to use this so much!

Answer (score 4):

Why not just do it like this ?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
   .parent{
      direction: rtl;
   }
}
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div1,
#div2 {
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
  #parent {
    direction: rtl;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cleanest solution IMO

Answer (score 1):

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gW8r2/2/)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}

.parent > div {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but from your jsFiddle it seems you just swapped the 2 divs around. The boxes need to stay the same but the right box needs to stack up on the left box is the effect I was looking for.

Comment: yes i swap both div to each other your question is reverse of the order if inline element thats why.

Comment: My question was to reverse the order the inline box stacks the elements, by default when the container is too small inline box will stack the left div up on the right div. I wanted the right div to stack up on the left div instead but maintain the original left div, right div standard order.